# How to change a DateTimeIndex in a pandas dataframe to all the same year?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this:

```
                   Charge 1     Charge 2
observation_date                      
1970-01-31        35.535318   0.073390
1970-02-28        27.685739   0.050302

...

2013-01-31        27.671290   0.296882
2013-02-28        26.647262   0.225714
2013-03-31        21.495699   0.362151
```

How do I re-index the data (the observation_date) so that all the years become 2013?

So 1970-01-31 becomes 2013-01-31, etc. I understand that there will be many times when the index will be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}').set_index('observation_date')
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df.index = df.index + pd.DateOffset(year=2013)
print(df)
```

yields

```
             Charge 1  Charge 2
2013-01-31  35.535318  0.073390
2013-02-28  27.685739  0.050302
2013-01-31  27.671290  0.296882
2013-02-28  26.647262  0.225714
2013-03-31  21.495699  0.362151
```

Comment: @user3914487 You should accept the answer as a valid answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I will write a function that update the year. 
I will go through a quick example here.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'observation_date':["1970-01-31","1970-02-31","1970-04-31"]})
l= df.observation_date

def updateYear(x):
  n= x.split("-")
  n[0]="2013" #We replace the year data, which is the first value by 2013
  return "-".join(n)
print updateYear("1970-01-31")


df['b']= df["observation_date"].apply(lambda x:updateYear(str(x)))
print df
```

Output::

```
  observation_date           b
0       1970-01-31  2013-01-31
1       1970-02-31  2013-02-31
2       1970-04-31  2013-04-31
```

In your case:

```
df= pd.read_csv(name)
df.index = df.index.apply(lambda x:updateYear(str(x)))
```

Answer (score -1):

not sure if I understand your question, but you can search for year startswith 1970 and replace with 2013

eg.

> new_date = re.sub('1970', '2013', observation_date)